# Coerce columns of two different dataframes to the same data type

Tags: python, pandas, format

I have two dataframes that are structured as such:

```
print(product_combos1.head(n=5))
             product_id  count  Length
0            (P06, P09)  36340       2
1  (P01, P05, P06, P09)  10085       4
2            (P01, P06)  36337       2
3            (P01, P09)  49897       2
4            (P02, P09)  11573       2

print(testing_df.head(n=5))
                     product_id  Length
transaction_id                         
001                       [P01]       1
002                  [P01, P02]       2
003             [P01, P02, P09]       3
004                  [P01, P03]       2
005             [P01, P03, P05]       3
```

How can I coerce the "product_id" column of the `testing_df` so that it is in the same format as the column in the `product_combos1` df? (ie- in parenthesis instead of brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python tuples are show in parentheses.  lists are shown in brackets.

Change the dataframe

```
testing_df['product_id'] = testing_df['product_id'].apply(tuple)
testing_df 

                     product_id  Length
transaction_id                         
1                        (P01,)       1
2                    (P01, P02)       2
3               (P01, P02, P09)       3
4                    (P01, P03)       2
5               (P01, P03, P05)       3
```

Make a copy

```
testing_df.assign(product_id=testing_df.product_id.apply(tuple))

                     product_id  Length
transaction_id                         
1                        (P01,)       1
2                    (P01, P02)       2
3               (P01, P02, P09)       3
4                    (P01, P03)       2
5               (P01, P03, P05)       3
```

---

Unless of course, those are actually strings.  Then just replace the brackets with parentheses.

```
testing_df.assign(product_id=testing_df.product_id.str.replace('\[(.*)\]', r'(\1)'))

                     product_id  Length
transaction_id                         
1                         (P01)       1
2                    (P01, P02)       2
3               (P01, P02, P09)       3
4                    (P01, P03)       2
5               (P01, P03, P05)       3
```

Comment: The only issue is that the first line of my df has gone from being `['P01']` to `('P01',)` I dont know why the "," has been added to the first row

Comment: Ahh, so the column elements were lists and you applied `tuple`.  Yeah, the other dataframe didn't have length one tuples. This one does have length one lists.  Python displays length one tuples with `(x,)` that comma to differentiate from an expression `(x)`.  Which would just evaluate to `x`

Comment: Would this cause any complications when I try to compare the two dataframes? Please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515412/pandas-return-partial-matches-between-rows-of-two-dataframes) if you can help.

Comment: When I run the code above, the length column disappears from the `testing_df` and when I try to re-add it I get the following error: `KeyError: 'product_id'`

Comment: There are a few things above in which you can run.  Which code are you running?  For example `testing_df.product_id.str.replace('\[(.*)\]', r'(\1)'))` Only produces the new `product_id` column.  However, the `assign` method produces a new copy of the dataframe with the new column overwriting the old one.  You have to assign the result to a variable.  That variable could be the same as the old one if you choose.

Comment: I am trying the very first method, "change the dataframe" but when I run it, the `'Length'` column disappears

Comment: When I first convert to tuple and then try to re-calculate the length column, i get the following error `KeyError: 'product_id'`

Comment: That error is saying that product_id isn't a column name. This can happen when there are other characters in the column name that aren't printed or are white space.

Comment: Run 'testing_df.columns[0]' and tell me what that returns

Comment: Before and after running the tuple conversion it returns `product_id`

Comment: Its working now. Instead of assigning the results of the conversions to a new df, I simply iterated over the original and the problem disappeared.